# Can you store multiple user input data into single variable - Python 3.6

Tags: python, variables, user-input, python-3.6

python noob here. I'm sure this is an easy question..
Is it possible to get numerical data collected from multiple user input questions into a single variable? For example, if I wanted to ask a user three questions:

```
int(input("What is your yearly income?"))

int(input("What is your partner's yearly income?"))

int(input("Enter any additional income"))
```

Can you store all of that data collected directly into a single variable named `total_income`. What I would like is to be able to get a sum total into a single variable.

Comment: Input in a single line(separated by space) or in multiple lines?

Comment: Just my curiosity, why would you stores each of your input into a separated list in the example given??

Comment: I just removed the square brackets. I actually forgot to remove it as I copy and pasted it. I originally had a separate variable for each question that stored the input data in a list form. I was hoping to just sum each list into one master list but that failed.

Comment: for your edit : you need to change the text in `input('bliblabla')` to tell the user to enter all values in the line, separated by space, don't change the suggested `split()` method. The solution provided by @deepansh-sachdeva is more ergonomic for you and the user...

Comment: the message should be like `input("Enter your yearly income, your partner income and any additional income separated by a space").split()`

Comment: Ah very good, I see. Is there ever times that arguments get passed through the split()?

Comment: You pass the chain that will be used to split the string, i.e. you will often see `split(",")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be helpful:

```
t = 0

t += int(input("What is your yearly income?"))
t += int(input("What is your partner's yearly income?"))
t += int(input("Enter any additional income"))
```

Comment: Deepansh Sachdeva, thank you very much. This is very simplistic and just what I needed. I was making it too complicated.

Comment: @TTom Glad to know.  Also, please accept my solution if it solved your query and do upvote if you found it useful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If your input in a single line(separated by space):

```
a=sum(map(int,input().split()))
print (a)
```